# Ubuntu graphic designers: Why the strokes look pixelated when I print on paper using Gimp?

Tags: graphics, display-resolution, gimp, vector-drawings, cmyk

When I print on A3 or A4 paper looks pixelated, the same for the text manipulation. I use to save designs to .pdf or .tiff and then I open them on Illustrator and modify things, but I don´t want to do that. I love Gimp!
I know it´s not a 100% ubuntu question but I guess some ubuntu graphic designers on Linux will have experienced this problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gimp is a bitmap editor where images are made of pixels. Check the print definition (`Image>Print size` in Gimp). Below 150PPI things will look pixellated.

Illustrator is a vector graphics editor, if you want to edit vector graphics with perfect scaling, use Inkscape.

Comment: Ok. Thanxs a lot! I will keep this in mind. I will use inkscape.